# Show Error in OneSignal if (r.getData()) required data type boolean

Tags: android, android-studio, push, onesignal

```
OneSignal.getNotifications().requestPermission(Continue.with(r -> {

            if (r.isSuccess()) {
                if (r.getData()) {
                    // `requestPermission` completed successfully and the user has accepted permission
                }
                else {
                    // `requestPermission` completed successfully but the user has rejected permission
                }
            }
            else {
                // `requestPermission` completed unsuccessfully, check `r.getThrowable()` for more info on the failure reason
            }
        }));

Required type: boolean
Provided: Object
```

How can I solve this issue while implementing OneSignal in an android studio project?

Answer (score 0):

While my issue is somewhat different, I was having a similar issue with this part of the code when trying to get it to build for Android in my react-native project.

My error was:

```
MainApplication.java:91: error: cannot find symbol
    OneSignal.getNotifications().requestPermission(Continue.with(r -> {
                                                   ^
  symbol:   variable Continue
  location: class MainApplication
```

The fix was to comment this block of code out entirely, as the comment above the code says:

```
    // requestPermission will show the native iOS notification permission prompt.
    // We recommend removing the following code and instead using an In-App Message to prompt for notification permission
```

Unfortunately, the documentation is out of date and this comment is incorrect, as it's mentioning the "native iOS notification permission prompt."

Considering this is Android, I'm assuming this is "copy-and-paste" where they just copied and pasted big sections of code and documentation and didn't proof-read it very carefully.

Regardless, commenting out this section allowed the android version to build. (I am using React Native).

Or better, you could even delete the code, although you will need to figure out the correct way to prompt the user for the notification permissions.

Here's the original code that I commented out:

```
   // OneSignal.getNotifications().requestPermission(Continue.with(r -> {
    //     if (r.isSuccess()) {
    //       if (r.getData()) {
    //         // `requestPermission` completed successfully and the user has accepted permission
    //       }
    //       else {
    //         // `requestPermission` completed successfully but the user has rejected permission
    //       }
    //     }
    //     else {
    //       // `requestPermission` completed unsuccessfully, check `r.getThrowable()` for more info on the failure reason
    //     }
    // }));
```

Comment: Your error should have been solved importing Continue: import com.onesignal.Continue;